# Padding bottom with max height

Tags: html, css

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <iframe src="...."></iframe>
   </div>
</div>
```

The wrapper div has CSS:
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     height: 0;
     padding-bottom: 56.25%;
     overflow: hidden;

The iframe has CSS:

```
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border: 0;
```

The container has CSS:

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
margin: 0 auto;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
max-width: 1280px;
max-height: 720px;
```

I'm trying to protect the aspect ratio 16:9 of the iframe as the window resizes and also maintain a maximum height for it of **100% - 67px** calc(100% - 67px). How can I do the two at the same time?

Comment: please provide the link of the iframe and explain more if you can

Comment: The padding-top trick for aspect-ratio doesn't respect a max-height. You need to change the parent width. If you have a navigation bar on the bottom/top and the aspect-ratio is overflowing it, you need to change the width of the parent. So let's say your bar is height: 50px and parent is width: 100%, you need to change parent to width: calc(100% - 25px), half of it's height.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. Ended up making another wrapper for the wrapper to get the effect of both.

The inner wrapper ensures that the aspect ratio is retained as padding-bottoms' value is scaled from width. The iframe fills it's container, and the outer wrapper provides the max-width so that it stops expanding after 865px.

```
.video-wrapper-wrapper {
    max-width: 865px;
    margin: auto;

    .video-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        padding-bottom: 82%;

        iframe {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I want full width . I mean 100vw?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using padding to set the height, set the height to the viewport width:

```
height: 56.25vw; /* 16:9 */
```

You can then set a max-height to whatever you like.

Comment: This will only work on fullwidth viewports. `%` cares about its container, `vw` doesn't. Also, another formula to get 56.25 is `calc(100% / (16/9))`. Just swap the `16/9` with whatever ratio you want.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to wrap the entire thing in an element with `max-height: ___; overflow: hidden`.